# How to create a multi-select parameter with a uniqueidentifier?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, uniqueidentifier

I am developing an SSRS 2008 R2 RDL file.  Now, I am trying to add a report parameter which should be a multi-select.  Previously I have worked with multi-select parameters but they have always been CHARACTER data types before.  So in my main dataset my code was:

```
;WITH Cte AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        1 as id, 
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE( (select @IncidentType),  ',' , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Names 
) 
SELECT 
    id, 
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Names
INTO #incident_types     
FROM Cte 
CROSS APPLY Names.nodes('/M') Split(a)
```

(And in my RDL file this IncidentType report parameter allows multiselect)

But now IncidentType is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER datatype.  I have tried the SSRS JOIN function but this is still giving me same error in SSRS when I run this:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'Incidents'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

How do I code for this by passing in multiple uniqueidentifiers?

I tried the solution below that you posted:

```
CAST(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS Names
```

But this gave me this error now:

```
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 62
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

At the top of my sproc I have:

```
declare
    @FacilityID varchar(MAX) = null,
    @ProgramID uniqueidentifier = null,
    @ServiceDateStart smalldatetime = null,
    @ServiceDateEnd smalldatetime = null,
    @IncidentType varchar(MAX) = null

SET @IncidentType = '864EA130-F36B-4958-B51F-EE9DBD35D804,671A8EB3-8298-40DB-BD66-93309904E463,ACA1EB55-3D66-467B-8388-CC42FCFB00F3
SET @FacilityID = '83B465B8-28DD-4F37-9F2D-A4D5E38EE7FB,3EC657F7-655F-43FB-8424-2A8914E7C725,B2064474-5C9B-4884-B1D7-4FCE1C804DF7'
```

But the line that causes this error is:

```
   AND (@IncidentType is NULL OR event_definition_rv.event_definition_id in (SELECT Names FROM #incident_types))
```

cause I can run these lines without errors:

```
select * from #incident_types
select * from #facilities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the unsplit values as uniqueidentifier:

```
    ;WITH Cte AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        1 as id, 
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE( (select @IncidentType),  ',' , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Names 
) 
SELECT 
    id, 
    CAST(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS Names
INTO #incident_types
FROM Cte 
CROSS APPLY Names.nodes('/M') Split(a)
```

Comment: Paul, can u have another look please?

Comment: Can you show your entire code?  `Running EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#incident_types'` shows that the #incident_types table is of type GUID.  And I had no trouble using a `WHERE x in (SELECT Names from #incident_types)` clause, so I think maybe the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I must have misentered the IncidentType cause now my sproc is working with your logic!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *But the line that causes this error is:*
>
> ```
> AND (@IncidentType is NULL OR event_definition_rv.event_definition_id in (SELECT Names FROM #incident_types))
> ```

Since @IncidentType is a **multivalued** report parameter, 
you can't use `@IncidentType Is NULL` in your report's Dataset Query because it messes up the sql code and it become unpredictable.

Also "*A multi-value parameter cannot include null values*" so it's useless to check if the parameter Is Null.
You could maybe use a [possible workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931993/7794769) like this:

```
 AND ('NULL_FLAG' IN (@IncidentType) OR event_definition_rv.event_definition_id IN (@IncidentType))
```

See [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/aa337292(v=sql.90)#writing-queries-that-map-to-multivalued-report-parameters) where it says:

> - The query must use an IN clause to specify the parameter.
>
> ### Note:
>
> The report server **rewrites queries** for data sources that cannot
>   process parameters as an array. Rewriting the query is necessary to
>   produce the intended result. A query rewrite is triggered when a
>   parameter is defined as multivalued and the query uses an IN statement
>   to specify the parameter. If you build a query that does not include
>   the IN statement, **be aware that you are circumventing the logic the report server provides to support multivalued parameters**.