# Optional multi-valued parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have 3 multivalued parameters in my report.Out of them 2 are optional.
Is there any way to get the results in the report with out selecting any from the 2 optional parameters.

My stored proc checks the mulivalued parameters  as (States IN  (SELECT * FROM Split(@State,',')))

I have done this for a single valued parameter with WHERE CustomerId = @CustId OR @CustId IS NULL.

**WorkAround:**
I selected 'Allow null value', it is throwing this error
"A multi-value parameter cannot include null values"

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49786027/7794769) for a possible explanation\solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at this article on [Passing Multivalued parameters](https://bi-rootdata.blogspot.com/2012/09/efficient-way-of-using-all-as-parameter.html).

Basically the above link contains a workaround to meet your requirement for an optional multivalued parameter. The steps to achieve this are as follows:

1. Replace "ALL" with " " (BLANK) in the parameter's dataset query.
2. Assign -1 as default parameter value for your multivalued parameter.

Comment: Thanks will try this out ...looks like it will solve my issue...thanks again

Comment: When I try to check that article, it's blocked for me.

Comment: @Naomi, Post have been moved to https://bi-rootdata.blogspot.com/2012/09/efficient-way-of-using-all-as-parameter.html