# auto display for report data with multivalue parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with some multi-value parameters, but when displaying the report I have to press the 'view report' button to show report data,
I added default values to the parameters but still it waits till I press the button and this is giving me headache, I have a set of not nullable parameters ranging between multi-value dropdown lists to simple strings  and I really need it to render the report with the givien default values without waiting for user to press anything

Comment: Please take a look into this similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917261/optional-multi-valued-parameters-in-ssrs/12931993#12931993

Comment: my problem is not passing the value or querying the data, my problem is that the report viewer is holding the data and isn't rendering it even though default values are supplied until user presses 'View Report' Button, I just want it to display it automatically

Comment: It does look like @Aftab's solution in the other question will exactly allow you to do that.

Comment: yeah you are right, it did work