# Optional multi-Select parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

My question is very similar to the following one:

[Optional multi-valued parameters in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917261/optional-multi-valued-parameters-in-ssrs)

The only complication is that the multiselect is part of a cascading parameter. So for every teacher, this multi-select will provide them with a list of all their classes. However, If neither parameter is selected I want it to return all the data.

The link provided in the answer is dead. Can someone help please.

Thanks,

Comment: @Aftab Ansari you originally posted the answer. Could you help please.

Answer (score 0):

Multivalue parameters require a value to be selected. The workaround for making a parameter "optional" is to have all values selected or have an "All" value available.

In the dataset that populates the Class dropdown list, you can union an "All" option to the results. Of course you would need to account for this value in your main query as well.