# How to allow blank values for multitple parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I have multiple parameters for a report in SSRS Report Builder. I want all the parameters to allow blank values if no selection is necessary, but when I try to run the Report, the first parameter will allow a null/blank value and it will prompt me for the rest of the parameters. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you set `Allow Blank Value` & `Allow Null Value` for all the parameteres?

Comment: Yes, I have that set for all parameters.

Comment: Two of the parameters are specified Available Values and two parameters are Date Ranges. It will pass the first blank value, but will prompt me for the second parameter and will not allow me to go on without selecting a parameter.

Comment: In the `Available Values` make sure to add Blank and/or NULL values.

Comment: If `Available Values` comes from query `UNION` it to bring Blank and/or NULL values.

Comment: Ok, How would I do that? Could you possibly provide me with an example?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49786027/7794769) for a possible explanation\solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `Allow Blank Value`(and/or `Allow NULL Values`) for all the parameteres.

   [image]
2. If the `Available values` are set, make sure your `available values` for the parameter brings Blank(and/or NULL) values.

   If it comes from query. Update your query something like this:

   `SELECT FieldX FROM Table1 
   WHERE blah=blah 
   UNION`
   `SELECT '' 
   UNION`
   `SELECT NULL`

   If it is specify values then specify Blank and NULL values

   [image]
3. Set the `Default values` to pull the blank(OR NULL) depending on your requirement. For Blank leave the value as empty.

   [image]
4. Final thing your query which produces the data can handle Blank(and/or NULL) values.

Comment: You cannot check both "Allow null value" and "Allow multiple values" or you will get the error "A multi-value parameter cannot include null values".