# Optional multi Select parameter Selection - SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report with multi select parameter option. I'm able to either select few or all. But in my scenario the parameter section itself is optional. If nothing is selected no data should come based on the parameter.

Is there a way to do that in SSRS?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658441/how-to-allow-blank-values-for-multitple-parameters .

Comment: @AnupAgrawal That example does not utilize multi select paramater and in my case it's multi select. So i'm not able to set null value to it.

Comment: You can do the same as suggested in that example. Allow blank/null values and modify the query to handle the blank/null values.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal With Multi select enabled, if i check Allow Null it's throwing error "A Multi-value parameter cannot include Null values"

Comment: What about the blank value? Does it allow you to select blank value along with the multiselect?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal It does allow blank value.

Comment: Great. Now Just update your query to accept Blank value as one of the available value and then update your query accordingly to show no data when blank value is selected.

Comment: That works but Can i have option to not select the paramater itself in SSRS leaving it empty with a multi select parameter? Basically, I want to optionally Select a paramter

Comment: Default the parameter so select the Blank value then you do not have to do anything.

Comment: Agree with the @newGuy. Default it to blank.

Comment: Still it is asking me to select a parameter value if I dont select any! :( Not sure if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49786027/7794769) for a possible explanation\solution.