# Allow user to skip a multi-value and use non-query list parameter in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to be able to use or not use an "Allow multiple values" parameter. So far, all I've found is how to add "blank" or "null" as a parameter default, but that only pulls all the values that are blank or null into the result set, it doesn't allow me to skip the parameter.

Also, I use a shared dataset, not a stored procedure, and can not use a specified query list (there would be over 2.8m records), I need to allow users to type the list manually in a text box or skip entirely.

I will try anything, as long as the data values are manually entered or can be skipped.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

I hope some more detail will help generate an idea. I am working in a medical environment, developing a series of reports for users who will choose from requesting Provider information, or Physician information, never both at the same time.

I just tried a suggestion, setting the ProviderNPI parameter properties to Default Specified to: ="NoEntry" and edit the query to add: WHERE (FieldProviderNPI IN (@ProviderNPI) or @ProviderNPI = 'NoEntry').

To run the report, I entered 1 week in the date range parameters, entered a valid PhysicianNPI number in @PhysicianNPI, and left the default NoEntry in the @ProviderNPI text box.

The results pulled 1.8m records, all with ProviderNPI numbers in the ProviderNPI column, and various or blank numbers in the PhysicianNPI column, none of which were the number I entered as @Physician.

I expected 34 records for that physician, with various ProviderNPIs.

Does anyone have a way to allow skipping a multi-valued parameter in my environment of shared or embedded datasets only, no stored procedures?

Comment: What is wrong with a NULL being passed in? You just need to modify your where predicate to handle it. (OR @MyParameter IS NULL)

Comment: The null option receives an error:  "A mutli-vale parameter cannot include null values." and just adding the code "OR @Myparam IS NULL" to the dataset query does nothing. Do you mean using it in some other way?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49786027/7794769) for a possible explanation\solution.